# Neo4J connection timed out in Spring Boot 2.2.4 but not in 2.0.5

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm building a Spring Boot application with neo4j. I have an issue connecting to a deployed database when I'm running on Spring Boot 2.2.4. In an other project with Spring Boot 2.0.5 it works, but when I upgrade that project to 2.2.4 it also breaks with the same exception.

The weird thing is that it also works on 2.2.4 locally when using a local Docker image.

I get the following exception when I try to connect to a deployed neo4j instance in the cloud using an uri of the form **bolt://35.xx.xx.xx:7687** AND on Spring Boot 2.2.4:
[image]

If I run my docker image and I change the connection uri to **bolt://localhost:7687** it also works perfectly fine on Spring Boot 2.2.4.

Even in my gitlab CI/CD pipeline the test works fine using a service inside the pipeline, also with the same neo4j image.

This is my **build.gradle**:
[image]

And these are the versions effectively installed:
[image]

I also can always use browser to connect to my database that's why I assume that it has something to do with the versions instead of my cloud configuration.

Anyone any idea what I have to change on my configuration?

Thanks in advance!

---

We run following versions:

- neo4j 3.5.14
- Spring Boot 2.2.4
- Java 11

---

**EDIT 1**
As someone proposed, I also setup a very simplistic example application (https://neo4j.com/developer/java/) using just the neo4j driver v4 with my GCP instance of Neo4J. This works perfectly fine.

---

**EDIT 2**
My application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://35.xxx.xxx.xxx:7687 # <- in prod
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687 # <- in dev
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://neo4j:7687 # <- in CI/CD
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=****
spring.data.neo4j.embedded.enabled=false
```

The different environments are splitted in seperate property files that set the spring active profile. Im always testing this with replacing the localhost one in the application-dev.properties to the public ip.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see if a simple application based on just the neo4j-java-driver 4.0 would result in the same problem. I do not have a GCP instance at hand but this looks definitely for now like something network/firewall/port mapping related.

Comment: @meistermeier as you asked I just setup a simple Java app following this example (https://neo4j.com/developer/java/) with my GCP instance. It works perfectly fine there. Because of this and also that it works with an older Spring version, I don't think it's something with my server config, but rather something with versions of my dependencies.

Comment: The real change between SB 2.1 and 2.2 and the SDN/OGM dependency is that we changed the underlying driver from 1.7 to 4.0. This is the reason why I asked for the confirmation, thanks. Have to think about this.

Comment: One more question for clarification: You are just substituting the uri in the `application.properties`, right?

Comment: Yes, updated the question :)

Comment: If you don't depend on the `neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter` (you are not using its properties for configuration), could you remove this dependency? There is no need for it if your are using plain Spring Data Neo4j. Just a wild guess for now: You are ending up with an unconfigured `Driver` bean from the starter that eagerly wants to connect to localhost and you have no local server running when trying GCP.

Comment: Tried that, but still the same exception. Was indeed worth a try I guess

Comment: Hi @JC97, are you using App Engine Flex? or which GCP product are you deploying in?
Is this issue persisting?

Comment: Hello @BraulioBaron, the neo4j instance runs in a seperate compute instance VM,  our spring app runs in App Engine Standard. This issue is also happening when running the app locally trying to connect to the Compute Engine instance. But since connecting via the browser and logging in afterwards (which uses bolt) I don't assume its a gcp configuration issue, but a version issue from one or more of the dependencies I used in the Spring app.

Comment: @meistermeier , BraulioBaron, any update regarding this issue?

Comment: Given that this could be related to dependencies and Spring Boot Version 2.2.4, it worth to post same issue on the [Spring-boot GitHub issues](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues). I mean, you have tried with a smaller and simpliest app using just the neo4j driver v4 and it works. And with the previous version it worked just fine...

Comment: Done: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20305

Comment: Did you check your encryption settings? 

Driver 1.7.x used in Spring Boot 2.1.x defaults to encrypted traffic trusting all certificates, Driver 4.0.x used in Spring Boot 2.2.x defaults to non-encrypted traffic. If your server requires encryption, than it you need to configure the 4.0.0 driver to do so. There's a property for it in the custom starter or you can do this through OGM configuration.

Comment: Using 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j', the encryption setting seems not to be exposed in the properties file. with 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter', it is exposed but I can't use the neo4j @Query in my repository.

Comment: Adding both dependencies seem to work if I set it up with the configuration parameters of the 2nd package, not the org.springramework package. I also don't need to set the encrypted parameter to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final setup (and solution) was to use only following dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j'
implementation 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver-spring-boot-starter:4.0.0.1'
```

And use following settings in the properties file:

```
org.neo4j.driver.uri=bolt://35.xx.xx.xx:7687
org.neo4j.driver.authentication.username=neo4j
org.neo4j.driver.authentication.password=neo4j
org.neo4j.driver.config.encrypted=false
```

Encryption wasn't the problem, but the settings had to be set to `org.neo4j.driver` instead of the `org.springramework.boot` dependency. The springframework dependency is still needed to use `@Query` etc in the repositories, thats why I needed both.